# About Kurosch-Ore theorem

Tags: reference-request, lattice-theory

Where can I find the proof of Kurosch-Ore theorem in lattice theory? 
The statement of this theorem is: Let $L$ be a modular lattice with $0$ and $1$ that satisfies both chain conditions. Then for any element $a$ in the lattice, any two decompsiton of $a$ into independent and indecomposable element can be put in 1-1 correspondence.

Comment: Also posted on math.SE: [About Kurosh-Ore theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1592802).

Answer (score 2):

Birkhoff's *Lattice Theory* has a proof, summarized as follows by C. Faith, [Algebra II Ring Theory](https://books.google.nl/books?id=VI3_CAAAQBAJ):

[image]

Comment: But here we need each component are independent, that is, just like krull-schmidt decomposition in group theory, we need the intersection of any two components is 0. In Jacobson's book (GTM 30, p204). He has mentioned this theorem without proof.

Answer (score 2):

You might prefer the treatment in Chapter 2, section 2.3, of Algebras, Lattices, and Varieties by McKenzie, McNulty, and Taylor.  They develop the Kurosh-Ore theorem along with Dedekind's Transposition Principle toward a more general result on modular lattices (with finite chain condition), namely the Direct Join Decomposition Theorem, where Jonsson's proof is used to inspire the presentation.  DJDT takes up a lot of section 2.4, and I recommend two or more readings to appreciate it.

Gerhard "Needs Five Or More Readings" Paseman, 2015.12.29